# Another signal with sigtimedwait

Tags: c, linux, signal-handling

This code is handle SIGINT signal during 100 seconds or print timeout if SIGINT didn't arrive.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigset_t orig_mask;
    struct timespec timeout;

 
    sigemptyset (&mask);
    sigaddset (&mask, SIGINT);
 
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask) < 0) {
        perror ("sigprocmask");
        return 1;
    }
 
    timeout.tv_sec = 100;
    timeout.tv_nsec = 0;
 
    
    int v =sigtimedwait(&mask, NULL, &timeout);
    if (errno == EAGAIN) {
        printf ("Timeout\n");
        return -1;
       }
    if(v== SIGINT){
        printf("SIGINT\n");
        return 1;
        }

 
    return 0;
}
```

When code is in `sigtimedwait` if another signal than SIGINT will arrive, is the code will continue ? Or `sigtimedwait` will finish only when SIGINT will arrive?

In addition if before this code I will register to another signal like `signal(SIGUSR1, handle_sig);` , when the code in `sigtimedwait` and `SIGUSR1` will arrived ,is `handle_sig` will called?or it will blocked ?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    signal(SIGUSR1, handle_sig);// 
    sigset_t mask;
    sigset_t orig_mask;
    struct timespec timeout;

 
    sigemptyset (&mask);
    sigaddset (&mask, SIGINT);
 
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask) < 0) {
        perror ("sigprocmask");
        return 1;
    }
 
    timeout.tv_sec = 100;
    timeout.tv_nsec = 0;
 
    
    int v =sigtimedwait(&mask, NULL, &timeout);
    if (errno == EAGAIN) {
        printf ("Timeout\n");
        return -1;
       }
    if(v== SIGINT){
        printf("SIGINT\n");
        return 1;
        }

 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the behavior of your program compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. So read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: Why not just test the code?

Comment: @KamilCuk maybe it's depending on architecture. I ask about the concept of `sigtimedwait`

Comment: The online manual of sigtimedwait answers your questions (man 2 sigtimedwait). Especially, if you read the ERRORS section, tou'll get: 
EINTR  The wait was interrupted by a signal handler; see signal(7).  (This handler was for a signal other than one of those in set.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (code 1) When code is in sigtimedwait if another signal than SIGINT will arrive, is the code will continue ?

If `SIGKILL`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2` .... any other signal with default action to terminate the process will arrive, the process will be terminated. If signal `SIGCHLD` or `SIGURG` arrives, they will be ignored - the code will "continue" to be *in* `sigtimedwait` (because there is no handler to be executed for these signals). If a stop signal (SIGSTOP, SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU) the process will be stopped. When after `SIGSTOP` we resume the process (by sending `SIGCONT`), then `sigtimedwait` will return `-1` and `errno` will be set to `EINTR`. For more information, see [`man 7 signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [posix sigtimedwait](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigtimedwait.html) and [posix signal concepts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).

> (code 2) when the code in sigtimedwait and SIGUSR1 will arrived, will handle_sig be called?

Yes.

> or it will blocked ?

No. The signal handler will be executed, then `sigtimedwait` will return `-1` and `errno` will be set to `EINTR`.

(TBH why didn't you just test the code? Looks trivial to put some `write(1` in signal handler, compiler and run the process and send a SIGUSR1 signal to it and see what happens)

> maybe it's depending on architecture

It's not - the behavior depends not on architecture, but on the behavior of an operating system - on the underlying software that is responsible for forwarding and handling of signals to processes and managing them. An POSIX compliant operating system has to do what is specified by POSIX, independent on architecture it's running on.